# Ряд Тейлора с заданной точностью

Tags: c#

**Мой код**

```
using System;

namespace ConsoleApp
{
    class Program
    {
        public static int factorial(int i)
        {
            int fact;
            fact = 1;
            for (int j = 1; j < i; j++)
            {
                fact+= fact * j;
            }
            return fact;
        }
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {   
            Console.WriteLine("Введите eps");
            double eps = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());

            Console.WriteLine("Введите x");
            double x = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());

            int i = 0;
            double sum = 1;

            while (Math.Abs(sum) > eps)
            {
                i += 1;
                sum += Math.Pow(-1, i) * (Math.Pow(x, 2*i) / factorial(2*i));
            }
            Console.WriteLine(sum);
        }
    }
}
```

**Вывод в консоли:**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Почему в консоль выводиться "не число"?

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! текстовую информацию лучше прилагать в виде текста: а) читать легче; б) можно копировать; в) поиск работает. исправить текст вопроса можно, нажав [edit] ниже текста вопроса

Comment: *В чём заключается ошибка?* — запятая вместо десятичной точки?

Comment: @aleksandr barakin исправил описание